# Jest unit test cannot find component functions when using Vue3 script setup syntax (wrapper.vm property does not exist on type)

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs3, ts-jest, vue-script-setup

I am starting to use Vue3's SFC script setup syntax: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html

When I try to write unit tests for these components the Intellisense complains that the functions declared within these components do not exist.

The error is on the wrapper.vm

> Property 'functionName' does not exist on type

My question is am I missing a package or tool that can resolve this issue?

I can cast the wrapper.vm as any to resolve the issue but it is not ideal...

I have added more details below:

[image: test component]
[image: test component unit test with error]

I can run the unit test and it will pass successfully, however if I try to build the project I will receive an error.

[image: test success]
[image: build error]

Here are some of the related packages in my package.json

```json
"@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.4",
"jest": "^27.4.7",
"jest-serializer-vue": "^2.0.2",
"ts-jest": "^27.1.3",
"vite-jest": "^0.1.4",
"vue-jest": "^5.0.0-alpha.10",
"babel-jest": "^27.4.6",
"vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1"
"vue": "^3.0.5",
"vue-tsc": "^0.28.7",
"vite": "^2.4.4",
```

Example component:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const msg = 'Click me'
function click(): string {
  return 'clicked'
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="click">{{ msg }}</button>
</template>
```

Example test:

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'

import Test from './Test.vue'

describe('Test', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Test)

  test('Component Renders', () => {
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBeTruthy()
  })

  describe('click method', () => {
    test(`to return 'clicked'`, () => {
      expect(wrapper.vm.click()).toEqual('clicked')
    })
  })
})
```

Here is an example of casting the wrapper as any to resolve the issue but this is something I would like to avoid.

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
const wrapper: any = shallowMount(Test)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<script setup>` is closed by default, so `click` needs to be explicitly *exposed* with the [`defineExpose()` macro](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose):

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
function click(): string {
  return 'clicked'
}
   
defineExpose({ click })
</script>
```

Exposing `click` also makes it available on the wrapper `vm` instance's type.

Comment: If you only want it exposed in the test environment, you could wrap the call with a check on `NODE_ENV`. It's 'TEST' when testing.

Comment: @tony19 how change NODE_ENV for expose only in the test?

Comment: @KevinMendez If using Vite, try: `if (import.meta.env.MODE === 'test') { defineExpose({ click }) }`

Comment: @tony19 - Just FYI, wrapping this in an if statement triggers an ESLint error - 'defineExpose' is not defined. Oh, and it also doesn't seem to actually evaluate at runtime, I assume because this is a macro and not an import.

Comment: I can confirm that ESLint complains about defineExpose not being defined. So in general, is using defineExpose really the advised solution here?

Comment: it worked fine. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could do something like this

```
it('should my Funct do Something', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(ComponentName, {})

  // call function
  wrapper.vm.$.setupState.functionName()
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()

  //expect something here
})
```